# Question on embedding and subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

For the following prosistion:

> **Proposition:**  A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an embedding iff it is continuous and one-to-one and for every open set $V$ in $X$, there exists an open subset $A$ of $Y$ such that $f(V)=A\cap Y$ (from K.D.Joshi's Introduction to General Topology Text)

I want to know how to match certain aspect of it to the following definition for embedding of one space into another:

> **Definition:** Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{U})$ be topological spaces.  If $(A,\mathcal{U}_A)$ is a subspace of $(Y,\mathcal{U})$ and $f:(X,\mathcal{T})\rightarrow (A,\mathcal{U}_A)$ is a homeomorphism, then $X$ is said to be embedded in $Y$  and $f$ is called an embedding of $X$ in $Y$.

I am presuming that for the function $f$, mapping from the spaces $X$ to $Y$, $X$ and $Y$ comes with their own topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{U} $ respectively. $A$ is a subspace of $Y$ with its own subspace topology $\mathcal{U}_A$ but the $A$ in relation to $f(V)=(A\cap Y)\subset f(X)$, is an open subset of $Y$.  So to find the open subset $A$ in the proposition, how would I go about doing that or do I have to change anything about the $A$ from the definition?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Joshi's criterion is wrong the way you gave it: for every $V$ open in $X$ there should be a $U$ open in $Y$ such that $U \cap f[X]=f[V]$. That makes $f$ (when restricted to $f[X]$ in the codomain, and in its subspace topology) a homeomorphism between $X$ and $f[X]$ i.e. an embedding.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In the definition of embedding that I gave, I assumed it is commonly phrased similarly in the literature.  When it says a homeomorphic mapping from $f:(X,T)\rightarrow (A, \mathcal{U}_A)$, it actually imply that for any open subset $V$ of $X$ and some open $U\in \mathcal{U}$, $U\subset Y$,  $f(V)=f(X)\cap U$ where $A=f(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

Both propositions are equivalent, as you said $X,Y$ come with their own topologies, but $f(X) = A$ inherits its topology from $Y$, i.e. $U \subseteq A$ is open in $A$ iff $U = V \cap A$ for some open set $V \subseteq Y$, its topology is fixed by that of $Y$.

The first proposition says that the map $f: X \to A = f(X)$ is open, i.e. its inverse is continuous and the second says that $f$ restricted $f: X \to f(A)$ is an homeomorphism.

I think you made some typos in the first proposition, is this correct?

Comment: thank you for clarifying that up for me.  Sorry what typos did I made in the first proposition. I got the proposition from a text different from where the definition came from.  If there is a typo, please do let me know.  Thank you.